# When a process or thread gets blocked, does it wait forever for a notification or just sleep for a while?

Tags: multithreading, jvm, block

I stumbled into this question when I was reading “JVMs typically implement blocking by suspending the blocked thread and rescheduling it later” from  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04186/?S_TACT=105AGX52&S_CMP=cn-a-j

When we say a process or thread gets blocked when doing IO operations (read, write) or getting access to some exclusive resource (lock, synchronized), when will it get to re-execute? are they constantly waiting until getting a notification from somewhere or does it simply quit its turn and run again after a while?

Has it anything to do with the specified platform? os or jvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would devolve to the underlying OS that must provide threading support to the VM - has to be that way so that the Java app can co-exist harmoniously with all the other proceses and threads that are typically loaded on an OS - browsers, sidebars, anitvirus, video/audio players, Torrent clients, OS internal threads etc. etc.

The code of a blocked thread gets no CPU cycles at all.  A thread in that state is just an unused-for-now stack allocation and an extra struct/class pointer in a container in the kernel, waiting for something else to change its state.  If it remains blocked or an extended time, the stack may even get swapped out on a busy system.

So yes, they constantly waiting until getting a notification from somewhere.